# Is it possible to use WiFi-Aware on Windows or Linux?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, ad-hoc-network

I am currently doing research on the topic of [WiFi-Aware which is supported on Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware) since Oreo. While doing so I struggle to find any information concerning the following question:

Is there any way to enable WiFi-Aware / [Neigbhor Awarness](https://www.wi-fi.org/discover-wi-fi/wi-fi-aware) Networking on a PC running either Windows or Linux? So that you could advertise services to nearby mobile phones?

How can I solve this?

Comment: Considering this is an active project in development I would guess that either there is information about what products it works on or there is not. So, what has your own research shown you so far? Based on the little bit of Googling I've done on this, it appears that it is specifically targeted towards mobile computers. There doesn't appear to be anything inherent preventing laptops from using the spec, but there also doesn't seem to be any mention of its use on those systems.

Comment: [Supported Transports / Wi-Fi Aware | Ditto](https://docs.ditto.live/javascript/common/mesh-network/supported-transports#wi-fi-aware)

Answer (score 0):

Wi-Fi Aware is basically vaporware everywhere except Android.

Wi-Fi Aware / NAN is a descendent of the Apple Wireless Direct Link (AWDL) technology that Apple pioneered in iOS (and a year later, macOS) for AirDrop and some AirPlay scenarios. I believe it's also used for Handoff (where an app on your iPhone can send its state to a partner app on macOS, or vice-versa, so you can switch a task from laptop to mobile and back with ease). I think AWDL is also used a few other things, like the way a Mac can trigger mobile hotspot mode on a nearby iPhone.

I don't think Apple provides any APIs for third parties to leverage AWDL. But if you wanted to play with those pre-packaged uses, get a Mac and an iPhone and have fun.

Answer (score 0):

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53594406/3795597).

This is still **very much in flux**, and I haven't yet found a card that advertises compatibility with NAN. I will document my (Linux) findings within this answer.

On Linux, the previous "Wireless-Extension" ioctl-based interface to configure wireless (802.11) devices is being replaced by [`cfg80211`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/cfg80211). The `iw` tool exposes a command line interface to configure devices that implement the `cfg80211` interface (see [this matrix](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless#Utilities) that compares utilities).

Reading the `cfg80211` code, NAN interfaces [get assigned their own type](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0d85b27b0cc6b5cf54567c5ad913a247a71583ce/include/uapi/linux/nl80211.h#L3456) (position index 12 in the enum).

The `mac80211` subsystem supports virtual interfaces that can be [created with the `iw` tool](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw/vif). Reading the code of the `iw` tool, [there is an undocumented](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jberg/iw.git/tree/interface.c?id=f2d9f5b52677f5414dc194be94b5916d2b080eab#n206) (and likely **unstable/unsupported** for now) `__nan` parameter that can be used to create such interfaces, though it seems my hardware doesn't support it.

`iw` has a few NAN-related commands:

```shell
# iw |grep nan
    wdev <idx> nan start pref <pref> [bands [2GHz] [5GHz]]
    wdev <idx> nan stop 
    wdev <idx> nan config [pref <pref>] [bands [2GHz] [5GHz]]
    wdev <idx> nan rm_func cookie <cookie>
    wdev <idx> nan add_func type <publish|subscribe|followup> [active] [solicited] [unsolicited] [bcast] [close_range] name <name> [info <info>] [flw_up_id <id> flw_up_req_id <id> flw_up_dest <mac>] [ttl <ttl>] [srf <include|exclude> <bf|list> [bf_idx] [bf_len] <mac1;mac2...>] [rx_filter <str1:str2...>] [tx_filter <str1:str2...>]
```

It seems these commands [directly call](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jberg/iw.git/tree/nan.c?id=f2d9f5b52677f5414dc194be94b5916d2b080eab#n332) the kernel interface, which [bails out early](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/0d85b27b0cc6b5cf54567c5ad913a247a71583ce/net/wireless/nl80211.c#L14188) with `EOPNOTSUPP` (operation not supported) if the interface is not a NAN-type interface. Indeed, this is what you can observe if you try to use the above `iw` commands on your regular interface.

To summarize, on **supported hardware** (I am not sure what hardware is currently supported, another answer [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54214808/3795597) some Intel hardware may support it), the following may work:

```bash
iw dev ## or `iw phy`: look for the physical interface name, for me it's `phy0` (phy#0)
iw phy phy0 interface add nan0 type __nan # create nan interface using (currently) undocumented type
# On my hw, the above returns "command failed: Operation not supported (-95)"
iw dev # This time, look for the "wdev" index of the newly created interface, here 0x2
iw wdev 0x2 nan start pref 100 # Not sure if that command should be performed before or after
iw wdev 0x2 nan add_func type publish nan_test_whatever
```

I will try to edit this if the situation improves, if I get more info, or if I get my hands on compatible HW.